# C++ MFC How to draw selection rectangle?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a list control. I want to draw selection rectangle on my own.
For example: when i clicked on an item it will draw an selection ractangle on that item and the item is next to it (or can be somewhere else).

Can anybody tell me how to do that ?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you miss understand my point. I ask how to do it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To draw a focus rectangle, call the [DrawFocusRect function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162479.aspx). To enable Visual Styles, call the [DrawThemeBackground function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) ([Parts and States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210.aspx): `LBCP_ITEM` and `LBPSI_SELECTED`).

Either way, you will have to [create an owner-drawn List Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298352.aspx) to be able to adjust rendering. For an MFC [CListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y04ez4c9.aspx) control you have to override at least [CListBox::DrawItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc9hahtd.aspx) (and usually also [CListBox::MeasureItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7tccyw7.aspx)).

Comment: First i want to make it clear that the selection rectangle is the blue one which apeared when click on an item. Second what i mean here is a list control not a list box. So can you review this for me. Thanks

Comment: @user2652023: The concepts for implementing this in a [CListCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) are identical to those for a [CListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3ch0w2y.aspx) and [CListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y04ez4c9.aspx). If you are looking for specific information, please ask a specific question.

Comment: Ok i get it now, really appriciate your help